# I am not getting readable format data using CURL?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

Below is my code

```
$url = 'http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/feeds/bestsellers?apikey=xxxxx';
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                            'Content-Type: application/xml',
                                            'Connection: Keep-Alive'
                                            ));
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
print_r($data);
exit;
my output is ....
��ks�Ȓ&�}~EE�������;N���ִdkM�=gg6� ��(��;����*��fQ���'�E@�*+++�����!k����`��_�o���f�g�f8碒Es|��k��B�$����_�����|v6-���*�����\=h� ���<���5ƁC�Ƣ�e�<͔�� ��e����Ue�����W��zZV́��*�7YYP#?�ͯ�/�_�+ /`yY\�\�MV\����U&k�L0z��Y�(V���f�]e͔5Ӭf�@v)��JJz�8f�SYK6��Hd�.r��敬k�E�ʂ�b���K�mE?UЦhX�]Y����Le�=Y"%�,�ضh~�Y$c���P?L>%R��Ǣl~e���?���h{C���Bu��i  4g)����岻�1Q0�X΀��5+.�F4�Q$��ٟ�%t��G�ihg�ț[��|�+��iO� �W�^�$�fS��B�Y�d�j[VK��1�M��4�����d~�IQ���+������X�pϘT� A���eU�r�<��)Q ���o�;�B�-�r��G�F �}��K|����/̌���,A�0)�%�Kl��^��z�N�G����c��"ޡU�V:.⡅�-���O(������Z���<�O�ט~mMУ������7�y�΃kt��-���lo��nPd)�����foJ��׸�Z�;j��D����v�z)�KY�.5��,*����t}�4������_�|&���T��r�#�j�LL�tc�{Q�s�"xn�m+ ���,+�?Xc�NK�q'�/�����3,ב�H��s./�^&�+ Tk����}�4������R�O�2������jW���梺�_�����S��ZO�J�8�D���*�zγ�c���X�=�>�5��b'�a��{�����L^��K\��ݲl÷Ǿ�,��o��#�:p%��^D���q ��fs�h���ۃg�oOͿ����ڻ��uD�\]]�v�~���Gibd'%���SW�Z�m�4���������#��=���u�e1�y`��f9��u��4�ρLH�T�T�)�����B)w��n?/' ��)�ɦ��2��kX��R*�ۗ����6a�&*S��&�فaFT�=��Dj-oR�踉�= [ ���v=�n�å���4��W�6���`�K�"_v�m���0f��X��6���`�cz�ѢH�k��s)@�]';h�o�DQoe2�2�H��mwoղh�*����*�����jy*�i������)D��_�dA�gz���Rm'�y  d|�|u�u�V� ��/�����"w���jz�t����mw�ؾ�и&3H��sWɇ�A���� "�-";�E�� �k�9��:_v��(G��T�/�5�Qq�^C�ՋD}]62*ˏ#�\�]�21���%�Px8E����?�D��X#��P�w<#����.vz��,��}v���|�+�2�:fg�X�j@���V��:�o9V"�6��x^k�;�`m��E���ӟO��T��/����T��ʸD��;��{�Q}�-��{Ѩ�� ��eY�i���D����Y����W�=�Œ�Yx�~��&}�.�:�ޮ�����Y�1��rЉ�!Y��\���h� ,���d�kDV���[V�@k}�>��t�������E$G�l�<�4b�~?�}�vg�ϲ`�n� {�%�b*P�WLR�/C�ݞ�nG}+:��(��x�sД��<�`@X)E�S��@ۅ�q�UU�m���,�XR�02� �&�d���دV��^x]^���.%ި4��F4�-�1;n��{��Au歏_�@I   ?��S�.|���� �Rv S�I��Z���L�)ș�O�    4R�`G8�Y���$����|¬��ݵ7�ޚȸ�,���.�.�k���� pB���S�k���H��0v��-C�ش�莇{�U�n��ߩe7b�E��o��ul�1��E��8y��o��M-����6�2kd<-@W�X���o�UZ��2U4�-�����h��K)������0D��r6i�F�U����C�=6�\>��⃏� ��مZyD�fb�Ǖ�ޏF�*�x���A�c��5st���xl.|�s/�"��@< \�[��ؾ�!��A3K�$��F6�dbٞ�$"6��������c�-��������4�2����@w�z�s#��?���{��?>��;8�X�alJ�A���������C���l}pn��v���=���N��_2w3�2?2�ȣ/
```

please help me to solve this issue...

Comment: please properly format the code. I have formatted the code and it works for me

Comment: Please fix the formatting of this, it is unreadable.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`XML` is now deprecated and `JSON` is the supported format. The api returns data gzipped. So, you will have to decode the response appropriately.

```
$url = 'http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/feeds/bestsellers?apikey=<apiKey>&format=json';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                        'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                        'Content-Encoding:gzip'
                                        ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r(gzdecode($data)); // un-gzip before using it
```

Hope this helps.